# @keyframes not working, I have tried everything i can think of

Tags: html, css

for some reason, the @keyframes rule won't work for me can someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

the only fix I can think of is -webkit- but that doesn't seem to help at all.

```css
.keyframe {
  height: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: width 4s;
}

.keyframe:hover {
  width: 250px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes keyframe {
  0% {
    -webkit-background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-background-color: yellow;
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="keyframe"></div>
```

I was expecting the colour to change as the bar progressed to the maximum width, however, the bar does not change colour at all.

Comment: Transition != Animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the animation that will be called inside the `:hover`

also, add to the `animation` property the `forwards` key, to make it stop on the end of the animation (then it doesn't return to red). (I removed the `-webkit` from the CSS, because I don't think it is really necessary)

My tip also is to change the name of `keyframe` to something that specify what the animation do, like `change-bgColor` or similar.

```css
.keyframe {
  height: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: width 4s;
}

.keyframe:hover {
  width: 250px;
  animation: change-bgColor 4s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes change-bgColor {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  70% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="keyframe"></div>
```